# Фальшивые ошибки Java-компилятора

Tags: java

Писал все по схеме в книге. На любое найденное слово `class` пишет ошибку на букву c. Помогите, пожалуйста! Заранее благодарен!

Проблему вижу в том, что компилятор думает, что я написал русскими буквами. Исправить... не знаю, когда писал HelloWorld, то же самое.

```
public class ErstesBeispiel {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ersteZahl;
    int zweiteZahl;
    int ergebnis;
    ersteZahl = 8754;
    zweiteZahl = 398;
    ergebnis = ersteZahl - zweiteZahl;
    System.out.println("8754 - 398 = " + ergebnis);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Marchella, приведите точное сообщение компилятора. Возможно, есм не нравится, что `public class ErstesBeispiel` объявлен не в файле `ErstesBeispiel.java`.

Comment: @Marchella, а Вы случайно не копировали код из электронной книги со вставкой в среду разработки?

Comment: За заголовок ставлю пять, а по вопросу - неуд.

Comment: или может быть скопирован вместе с объявлением пакета